# GPG encryption for Excel file (command line)

Tags: excel, encryption, gnupg

I am testing automated encryption/decryption with GPG for various files. I've figured out everything I need for csv files, but I can't encrypt my own Excel files.

The following command encrypts a csv file as TESTFILE_20150327.csv.gpg:

```
gpg --encrypt -r RECEIVER "C:\Test_GPG\TESTFILE_20150327.csv"
```

I thought that it would work similarly for Excel, but the following code throws back a "can't open <>: Invalid argument"

```
gpg --encrypt -r RECEIVER "C:\Test_GPG\TESTFILE_20150327.xlsx"
```

I'm quite new to GPG and am not sure what needs to be changed to encrypt; similarly, since I can't encrypt an Excel file in the same way as I can a csv, I'm not sure if decrypting like a csv will work either. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gpg works equally well regardless of the file type being encrypted.

Can you verify the read permissions on the C:\Test_GPG\TESTFILE_20150327.xlsx file and the write permissions on the folder you're creating the encrypted copy in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Checking the Excel file, the permission is set so that anyone can open, copy, and change any part of this workbook. I created the folder/file myself, and write permissions are enabled. I created a new folder and moved the file there, and was able to encrypt. I'm not sure where the difference comes in, but that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using 
 
`message: openpgp.message.fromText(data)`
when you should be using
 
`message: openpgp.message.fromBinary(new Uint8Array(data))`
because the xlsx is compressed and therefore read as a binary file if you use 
`` data = fs.readFileSync(`file.xlsx`) ``

https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp#encrypt-with-compression